# Why haven't install predis on laravel 8

Tags: laravel, redis, predis

According laravel manual https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redis for install predis, need run: composer require predis/predis. When that command is running (for laravel 8) - appear next Error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - facade/ignition is locked to version 2.4.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - facade/ignition 2.4.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - facade/ignition-contracts 1.0.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - nunomaduro/collision v4.3.0 requires facade/ignition-contracts ^1.0 -> satisfiable by facade/ignition-contracts[1.0.1].
    - nunomaduro/collision is locked to version v4.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

In my composer.json:  "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",

What here is wrong))?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `facade/ignition` and `nunomaduro/collision` first to support PHP 8 in your project.

Running the following commands should update them accordingly.

```
composer require --dev facade/ignition nunomaduro/collision
composer require predis/predis
```

Answer (score 0):

i run comand: composer require --dev facade/ignition nunomaduro/collision and have got new Error:   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- facade/ignition[2.10.0, ..., 2.10.2] require facade/ignition-contracts ^1.0.2 -> found facade/ignition-contracts[1.0.2] but the package is fixed to 1.0.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- Root composer.json requires facade/ignition ^2.10 -> satisfiable by facade/ignition[2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.10.2].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

I have new laravel 8 project (blog) && use new Vagrant Homestead (with all updates) && i use laravel 8 manual)) may be laravel developers is a little busy and is a little tired to give full instruction in manual). I think may be for Laravel8 Homestead allready is not suitable  and need Docker and Sail... But project work (with the exception of predis) Now i use  phpredis. May be will try use docker... As for Vagrant&&Homestead - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#introduction i don't understand what is problem to use that technology .... god with they)...